# image base64 to jsonArray - cordova/android

Tags: java, android, json, cordova

I'm trying to send an image (from camera or gallery) by email with SMTP.
I have a smtp cordova plugin and I send the image (base 64) to the plugin as "attachmentsInBase64Format".
The plugin trying to do this:

```
JSONArray attachments = json.getJSONArray("attachmentsInBase64Format");

    if(attachments != null){
        for(int i=0; i < attachments.length(); i++){
            String fileFullName = attachments.getString(i);
            if(fileFullName.contains(":")){
                fileFullName = fileFullName.split(":")[1];
            }
            m.addAttachment(fileFullName);
        }
    }
```

and returns:

```
Value *my_base64_img_value* of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray
```

Comment: json.getJSONArray("attachmentsInBase64Format"); You are not passing a json array, you are sending "attachmentsInBase64Format" that is a string.

Comment: Entendi. E como eu consertaria isso no caso, isto é, preciso converter string pra json array?